# How to find the length of the second word in 3-word phrase without using loops or any built-in methods of java?

Tags: java

I want to know how you can find the length of the second word without using a for or a while loop and any built-in methods of java like substring, match, left or right...etc. This has to be done using the indexOf(); method and the char.
Sample input: The grey elephant ----> Sample output: Second letter has 4 words

I did this task using the for loop but our teacher restricted it, I want to know is that is there any way the for loop can be broken down, meaning keeping everything the same but removing the loop, and manually doing it. I don't want any other solutions, if you could just fix my code cuz the process is right and it works with the for loop. But I need it without it, I think if statements will do but idk where to put them.

Or if none work then I think it involves the overloaded version of the indexOf(); method. How would I use that?

Code:

```
else if (option == 2){
            int first = -1;
            int last = -1;
            for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length() && x > phrase.indexOf(x); x++){ 
                char n = phrase.charAt(x);
                if (n == ' ' && first == -1){ 
                    first = x;
                }
                else if (n == ' '){ 
                    last = x;
                    }
                }
                    int length = last - first - 1; 
                        System.out.print("Second word has "+length+" letters");
            }
```

Comment: Can you use recursion?

Comment: If you know that "each word is separated by a space" and you know that "each sentence has at least three words" I would use a combination of `String#indexOf` and `String#substring` to derive the length of the second word. This is true if you don't need to dynamically "select the length of the Nth word". If you do, then I'd use recursion as @AndyTurner mentioned.

Comment: two hints: 1. `indexOf` is overloaded, there is `public int indexOf(int ch)` and `public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`. 2. try to think about which char separates two words...

Comment: You could try the [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), but I am unsure if this is allowed

Comment: Yeah its not allowed

Comment: How would I use the the overloaded version of the indexOf(); method?

Comment: Can also try `String.split("\\s+")` to get a `String []` of all the words

Comment: Nope not allowed, how would i use the overloaded version of the indexOf(); method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            int index1 = phrase.indexOf(' ');
            int index2 = phrase.indexOf(' ', index1 + 1);
            System.out.println("Length of the second word is " + (index2 - index1 - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: The grey elephant 
Length of the second word is 4
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning world!
Length of the second word is 7
```

## [Update]

Posting the following update based on OP's request to find the length of the first word and that of the last word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            int firstIndex = phrase.indexOf(' ');
            System.out.println("Length of the first word is " + firstIndex);
            System.out.println("Length of the last word is " + (phrase.length() - phrase.lastIndexOf(' ') - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning world
Length of the first word is 4
Length of the last word is 5
```

Comment: @Hussain123: now that you've seen a way to solve the problem I strongly recommend that you consider what you found non obvious about it. You were advised to use only indexOf(). Did you spot that there were two variations of indexOf()? Is the idea of using one answer as one of the inputs to the next call clear? These are ideas you will use again and again in more complex problems. There's really good learning to be had here, look for ideas to be applied to the next problem.

Comment: How would you do it for the first and the last word? Also what is this variation of indexOf(); doing I have seen it somewhere but can u tell me in detail what is happening inside the brackets?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) documentation.

Comment: How would you do it for the third word, I got the first one working

Comment: Would you use LastindexOf(); for that one?

Comment: If the phrase consists of only three words, you can use `lastindexOf()` to find the length of the 3rd (last) word. I've already posted this solution in the **[update]** section of my answer. If the phrase consists of more than three words, you can use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) variation of `indexOf` to find the length of the 3rd word.

Comment: Hey Arvind can you check this out its really important

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487996/is-there-a-way-to-check-hidden-test-cases-for-an-assignment-the-code-is-shown-b

Comment: I've answered it. In case of any issue, feel free to comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how you can calculate the length of the 2nd word (assuming the separator character of the string is only one space.

```
    String str = "The grey elephant";
    int start = str.indexOf(' ');
    int end = str.indexOf(' ', start+1);
    int lengthSecondWord = end - start - 1;
    System.out.println("2nd word length " + lengthSecondWord);
```

Comment: for the first word the int start = str.indexOf(' ') gives you the length, for the length of the last word you can use the String method LastindexOf() and you can use the .length() method too

Comment: you are welcome :) doing sample exercises with String methods is good to get familiar how they work, also in Java 8 was introduced stream as interface and that added quite interesting methods to work on data structures...